# How to get data of datagridview in Crystal Report in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a Window Form in C#. i want that when i click get report the exact data of datagridview also show in crystal report viewer.

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            CrystalReport2 cos = new CrystalReport2();

            cos.SetDataSource(ds);

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cos;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you debug your code and check if the DataTable that you added to the Dataset is not null before this line of code: `cos.SetDataSource(ds);`

Comment: How can i check i am new please tell me

Comment: Do you want to generate the report on the selected Author name?

Comment: Yes.................... BeginnerCoder

Answer (score 2):

Dear Saima Follow the given  link.
What you are missing is Table in design mode.
Crystal report in design mode need to have a table that contains exactly the same field in your dataset
Then you can use your code and it will work well

Hope this helps

[Follow this Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28899/Crystal-Report-with-DataSet-and-DataTable-using-C)

Answer (score 0):

```
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from MRU1 where RegDate between '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString() + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString() + "'", con);

 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 sda.Fill(dt);


 RegisCrystalReport cos = new RegisCrystalReport();

 cos.SetDataSource(dt);

 crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cos;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting a piece of code without any text is often not very helpful.